# Why does OCTGN keep asking me to update? I already have the new version!

Tags: octgn

[OCTGN](http://www.octgn.info/) keeps asking me to update even though I've already updated to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This most likely happens because your shortcut points to an old version of OCTGN. Early this month, the OCTGN development group released an update that moved the current version of OCTGN to `My Documents\Octgn\OCTGN\OCTGN.exe` or `Documents\OCTGN\OCTGN\OCTGN.exe`. Your shortcut needs to point there. To fix it, right-click on it, select properties, and enter the first location (Windows XP) or the second (Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows 8, I assume) in the target field. Then click okay.